# Integrating Solr 8.9.0 and MongoDB 5.0 Community Edition

Tags: mongodb, solr, mongo-connector

I'm running Solr 8.9.0 and Java 14.0.1 on Linux, and I'm trying to integrate Solr and MongoDB 5.0 Community Edition. I have MongoDB running and loaded with data, and I've installed the mongo-connector.

I'm really struggling with what to do next. All of the documentation that I've found (see a few examples below) is several years old, inconsistent, incomplete and simply doesn't work.

Can anyone please share some documentation / advice on how to integrate Solr and MongoDB?

Thank you.

Muhammad

https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/02/03/indexing-mongodb-data-in-apache-solr

https://hub.packtpub.com/apache-solr-and-big-data-integration-mongodb/

https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr

https://chemifinder.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/integrating-mongodb-and-solr-part-3-integrating-mongodb-and-solr/

Comment: don't add greeting in the questions

Comment: What greetings?